# PHP/jQuery Instagram gallery on website

Tags: php, jquery, instagram

I'm looking to have a gallery on my website that contains the images from my Instagram account. I haven't been able to find my resources that explain the process of interacting with the API for this purpose. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Ideally the gallery would have folders by month, sort of like an archive feature.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this out? It seems straightforward.

http://snipplr.com/view/58083/

Comment: Or this... http://stuffthatspins.com/2012/03/30/display-instagram-picture-stream-really-easy-with-jquery-and-json/

Comment: As far as the first solution goes, I'm trying to do something that goes directly through instagram, and for the second solution you end up putting you access token and user id into a javascript request. Is it ok for other people to have access to my access token and user id?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the Instagram API and create a Javascript solution manually. But this will take time.

The API that you need is -

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

2. Or You can directly use a simple plugin like Youmax-PhotoMax.

PhotoMax will create an Instagram Gallery from your user account. The Archiving feature you will have to add manually into it. But most of features like filtering images based on @user or #hashtags will already be present in there.

[You can check out the demos here.](http://demos.codehandling.com/youmax_demo/photomax_multiple_sources)